# How do I resolve this: The method received in the request-line is known by the origin server but not supported by the target resource

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

I have been trying to make a simple 2 number addition program using servlets and hosting it using tomcat 10.0 server, i was following a tutorial that worked well until this point and I am now unable to solve this, please point out any errors in the code
web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5" xmlns="https://JAVA.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
    <servlet>
    
        <servlet-name>ac</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.ali.Add</servlet-class>
    
    </servlet>
    
    <servlet-mapping>
    
        <servlet-name>ac</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/add</url-pattern>
        
    </servlet-mapping>
    
</web-app>
```

Add.java

```
package com.ali;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class Add extends HttpServlet
{
public void service(HttpServletResponse res,HttpServletRequest req) throws IOException {
    int i,j,k;
    i=Integer.parseInt(req.getParameter("n1"));
    j=Integer.parseInt(req.getParameter("n2"));
    k=i+j;
    PrintWriter out = res.getWriter();
    out.println("result"+ k);
}
}
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

    <form action="add">
    
        ne1 : <input type="number" name="n1"><br>
        ne2 : <input type="number" name="n2"><br>
        <input type="submit">
        
    </form>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Sorry if there's any problems with formatting and grammar, I'm new here...

Answer (score 0):

Solved-
Solution was to make servlet using the given tools within IDE(Eclipse) after that the program worked
I shouldn't have followed the tutorial blindly, i wonder how did his program even work though :/
Another solution is to just add ServletException in code